# Haskell type inference (ReaderT and tuple)

Tags: haskell, monads

Exploring this material: [Lens over tea](https://artyom.me/lens-over-tea-2) I've encountered an interesting (simple at first) point:

```
ex3 :: (a, b) -> (b, a)
ex3 = do
 a <- fst
 b <- snd
 return (b, a)
```

Everything's fine, but what type of monad does this function use (since we have a do-block inside). After a few attempts I arrived to this conclusion:

```
ex2 :: ReaderT (a, b) ((,) b) a
ex2 = ReaderT $ do
  a <- fst
  b <- snd 
  return (b, a)

ex3 :: (a, b) -> (b, a)
ex3 = runReaderT ex2
```

So, we have ReaderT that uses inner monad ((,) b). Interestingly enough - I got not enough satisfaction with this and decided to rewrite ex2 not using do-notation. This is what I got:

```
ex2 :: Monoid b => ReaderT (a, b) ((,) b) a
ex2 = ReaderT $ 
  \pair -> return (fst pair) >>= 
  \a -> return (snd pair) >>= 
  \b -> (b, a)
```

or even:

```
ex2 :: Monoid b => ReaderT (a, b) ((,) b) a
ex2 = ReaderT $ 
  \pair -> (mempty, fst pair) >>= 
  \a -> (mempty, snd pair) >>= 
  \b -> (b, a)
```

Both variants require b to have a Monoid type restriction. 
The question is: can I write this functions with (>>=) only and without using a Monoid restriction - like we have with do-notation variant? Apparently we do the same with or without do-notation. Maybe the even difference, that we have to construct monads at every step in the second and thirst fuctions and this requires us to state that "b" should be a monoid - some monoid. And in the first case we just extract our values from some monad - not constructing them. Can anybody explain am I thinking in the right direction?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You have not quite desugared this from `do` notation to `(>>=)` calls. A direct translation would look like this:

```
ex2 :: ReaderT (a, b) ((,) b) a
ex2 = ReaderT $
  fst >>= (\a ->         -- a <- fst
  snd >>= (\b ->         -- b <- snd
  return (b, a)))        -- return (b, a)
```

Also, you aren't actually using the monadness of `(,) b`, even though it fits into the slot here for the "inner monad" of `ReaderT`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ex3 :: (a, b) -> (b, a)
```

means, in prefix notation

```
ex3 :: (->) (a, b) (b, a)
       -----------m
                   ------t
```

Hence the monad is `m = (->) (a, b)` which is the Reader monad (up to isomorphism) with a pair as its implicit argument / read-only state.

You don't need a monoid. The plain reader monad is enough. If you want to use `ReaderT`, use the identity monad as the inner monad.

```
ex2 :: Monoid b => ReaderT (a, b) Identity (b, a)
ex2 = ReaderT $ 
  \pair -> Identity (fst pair) >>= 
  \a -> Identity (snd pair) >>= 
  \b -> Identity (b, a)
```

Of course, the code above could be simplified.

Comment: I was just trying to understand where that monad was and what type it had :)) Thank you,

Comment: Thank you all for clarifying me the main thing I've missed at the very beginning: there is no need to either ReaderT or (,) b monad instances when the functional arrow  (reader) is the only monad I need. Since the function signature is a monad we can use do-notation inside and every row inside the do-block is the monadic computation - thats the function which has the same argument - a tuple. And this do-version can be actually desugared like David Young suggested. No ReaderT, no partial tuple!! Finally this little puzzle has been solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

So to summarize:

1. Type of monad is (->) r - just function or simple reader;
2. How to desugar the initial function without do:

   ```
   ex3' :: (a, b) -> (b, a)
   ex3' = fst >>=
     \a -> snd >>=
     \b -> return (b, a)
   ```